# How to boot vhdx drives?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, boot, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup, vhdx

I recovered a bare metal backup for one hyper-v vm (2012 R2) in the form of 2 vhdx files.
How can I boot the backed up vm?
Should I burn into a USB/DVD or can I just use an unallocated drive space?

Comment: Please don't post [multiple questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/1008172/how-to-boot-a-recovered-bare-metal-backup) for the same problem. Instead, edit your question for more clarity.

Comment: Noted with thanks, I have just deleted the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully restored the backup directly from the vhdx drive. My issue was not being able to detect the Windows Image Backup within the Windows Repair Mode. The issue was fixed by moving the WindowsImageBackup directly under the C drive.
"As per the functioning of the System Restore utility, the WindowsImageBackup folder must be stored in the root of the volume it is store in. So for instance, if the WindowsImageBackup folder is stored in C:\Backups\System Restore Backups\New, you must move it to the following location: C:\"